# Puppeteer saved PNG is NOT transparent

Tags: css, background, transparent, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer to screen capture an HTML element with ID name.

The HTML element is with `border-radius: 50px` and I set Puppeteer with `omitBackground: true`.

The Saved PNG result gave me is a WHITE background, looks like it captured the BODY WHITE background.

`puppeteer: v1.13.0`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the page has a background color you want to remove that, and then use the `omitBackground: true` option of [page.screenshot](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.13.0/docs/api.md#pagescreenshotoptions):

```js
await page.evaluate(() => document.body.style.background = 'transparent');
await page.screenshot({
    path: 'example.png',
    omitBackground: true,
});
```

Comment: `await page.evaluate(() => document.body.style.background = 'transparent');` Awesome. this works!

Answer (score 1):

What `omitBackground: true` does is changing the **default** background color to transparent. According to [the documentation](https://paulirish.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/tot/Emulation/#method-setDefaultBackgroundColorOverride):

> Emulation.setDefaultBackgroundColorOverride
>   Sets or clears an override of the default background color of the frame. This override is used if the content does not specify one.

If the body has a `background-color: white;`, `setDefaultBackgroundColorOverride` won't change that.

Comment: Thank you! So they don't support it and it should not support that? @hardkoded

Comment: @W.Zhong you could report it on the github project and see what they say about this.

Answer (score 0):

it worked for my:

```
formatImage = {
        type: 'jpeg',
        quality: 100,
        fullPage: true,
        omitBackground: true,
};
```

I think that the omitBackgroun only works on JPEG type. Because I has the same error and it solves with the type: 'jpeg'